# Create DevExpress Dashboard in a project with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, devexpress

Hello Everyone I am new in StackOverflow so I may can't describe my problem well But I try my best and I am conting on you to help me with this ;
I have problem in myproject asp.net core wanna build dashboard with devexpress I already followed a tuto by devexpress but it seem something doesnt match when I try to install a package with NuGet  I can't find it I have already try to add the package source so it help me find it but still nothing , I really need to do somthing about it immediately .

---

Here is some link to know more about this issue

The package :DevExpress.AspNetCore.Dashboard

-the tips that I thought it could help me : https://docs.devexpress.com/Dashboard/119284/getting-started/build-end-user-dashboard-designer-applications/create-an-aspnet-core-designer?v=18.1

-the tuto I followed : https://docs.devexpress.com/Dashboard/119284/get-started/build-web-dashboard-applications/create-an-aspnet-core-dashboard-application

I use asp.net core version 2.0

DevExpress 17.2

Comment: Please ensure you has complete the step 3 and step 4  that is to add DevExpress Package Sources in the tutorial.

Comment: I already did it but still can't see the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress
>   18.1\Components\System\Components\packages

In the tutorial you refer to, the `Source` path added by it downloads the corresponding packages to a local folder, but because you did not download it, you cannot find the corresponding package using the path in the reference document.

Please refer to [this article](https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/116042/installation/install-devexpress-controls-using-nuget-packages/obtain-your-nuget-feed-url), **log in** to the account on the DevExpress official website, and click the **Obtain Feed URL**, an url including `your authorization key` and `api` will be generated.

[image]

Then when adding the package source, **change the Source path to the url** and continue to follow the tutorial.

[image]